# What kind of nefarious deeds can IP address Spoofing be used for?

Tags: network, ip-spoofing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What security risks does IP spoofing bring?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1009/what-security-risks-does-ip-spoofing-bring)

I found [this article](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/ip-spoofing-introduction), which seems pretty good but was written in 2003 so I'm not sure how up to date it is.

Can IP address spoofing still be used for:

- Denial of Service attacks
- Man in the middle attacks

Are there other types of attacks this can be used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP Spoofing with TCP over the open internet is impossible because of the [three-way-handshake](http://www.inetdaemon.com/tutorials/internet/tcp/3-way_handshake.shtml).   So you are limited to ICMP/UDP services or attacks on services available over the local LAN.  The local lan is an issue if you are able to sniff the network.  So this is a problem if you are on a broadcast network or using ARP poisoning on a switched network.  ARP poising is also a spoofed attack.

A good example of a spoofed icmp attack is the [Smurf DoS Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smurf_attack).  The UDP variant of this DoS attack is called the [Fraggle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraggle_attack).  (Who names these!?!??)  Also it should be noted that these attacks are **old** its unlikely that you'll find a vulnerable network.

So in conclusion IP spoofing has a very limited scope.  Because Its an attack that has been taken into consideration and its easy to prevent.

Comment: Ha, find me a network vulnerable to a smurf attack nowadays and i'll give you a cookie.

Comment: @k to the z yeah to be honest this is a very limited attack pattern.  I was hard pressed to find anything.

Comment: don't take it to heart.  You tried.

Comment: @Rook,could you please take a look at this:http://security.stackexchange.com/q/49487/35462