# What cryptographic flaw was exploited by Flame, to get its code signed by Microsoft?

Tags: cryptography, malware

Today, Microsoft released a security advisory warning that the "Flame" malware exploited a weakness in a cryptographic algorithm used by Microsoft Terminal Server Licensing Service, and was thereby able to get some of its code signed so it appeared to have come from Microsoft.

Here's what [Microsoft wrote](https://blogs.technet.com/b/msrc/archive/2012/06/03/microsoft-releases-security-advisory-2718704.aspx?Redirected=true):

> We have discovered through our analysis that some components of the malware have been signed by certificates that allow software to appear as if it was produced by Microsoft. We identified that an older cryptography algorithm could be exploited and then be used to sign code as if it originated from Microsoft. Specifically, our Terminal Server Licensing Service, which allowed customers to authorize Remote Desktop services in their enterprise, used that older algorithm and provided certificates with the ability to sign code, thus permitting code to be signed as if it came from Microsoft.

See also [this blog post from Microsoft](https://blogs.technet.com/b/srd/archive/2012/06/03/microsoft-certification-authority-signing-certificates-added-to-the-untrusted-certificate-store.aspx?Redirected=true).

So, what was the exploitable cryptographic algorithm that was used by Microsoft Terminal Service Licensing Service?  What was the cryptographic weakness that was exploited by Flame?  Are there any lessons we can learn from this incident?

Comment: I found this blog post that explains it a little bit better, in my opinion: http://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2012/06/flame-certificates-collisions-oh-my.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two vulnerabilities here:

- **Unrestricted code signing.** Microsoft gave users of Terminal Services the ability to get a signing cert that chains up to the Microsoft Root.  They inadvertently allowed this cert to be used for signing code.  Therefore, users could sign any code they liked and make it look like it was approved by Microsoft. Yikes!  Very bad.

  This vulnerability is exploitable on systems before Windows Vista (e.g., on Windows XP).  However, due to new hardening measures introduced in Vista, this vulnerability is no longer exploitable for code signing on Windows Vista or later, on its own.
- **Collision attacks.** One of the certs in the chain [uses MD5](http://lists.randombit.net/pipermail/cryptography/2012-June/002961.html).  MD5 is known to be vulnerable to collision attacks, and it is known how to use these attacks to exploit any certificate authority who uses MD5.  This made it possible for the attacker to get any code of their choosing signed, in a way that makes it look like it was approved by Microsoft.  (See @Hendrik's answer for more.)  This is also very bad.

  This vulnerability enabled them to bypass the Vista-related hardening.  Thus, the combination of these two vulnerabilities allowed the attackers to attack all Windows operating systems successfully: they were able to get their malicious code signed so it looked like it came from Windows.

These are two separate (but related) vulnerabilities.  Flame uses the two in combination, enabling Flame to successfully attack all Windows platforms.  These vulnerabilities have been present for many years.  Someone could have just as easily exploited the former vulnerability, though it would have only be successful against pre-Vista platforms.

Resources for further reading:

- An excellent blog post that explains all of this in more detail:  http://rmhrisk.wpengine.com/?p=52
- [Microsoft wrote](https://blogs.technet.com/b/msrc/archive/2012/06/04/security-advisory-2718704-update-to-phased-mitigation-strategy.aspx?Redirected=true):

  > The Flame malware used a cryptographic collision attack in combination with the terminal server licensing service certificates to sign code as if it came from Microsoft. However, code-signing without performing a collision is also possible.
- [Microsoft also wrote](https://blogs.technet.com/b/srd/archive/2012/06/06/more-information-about-the-digital-certificates-used-to-sign-the-flame-malware.aspx?Redirected=true):

  > by default the attacker’s certificate would not work on Windows Vista or more recent versions of Windows. They had to perform a collision attack to forge a certificate that would be valid for code signing on Windows Vista or more recent versions of Windows. On systems that pre-date Windows Vista, an attack is possible without an MD5 hash collision.
- The collision attack apparently involved development of a novel collision attack on MD5, different from the ones that were previously known in the open research literature.  See Ars Technica's reporting ([Crypto breakthrough shows Flame was designed by world-class scientists](http://arstechnica.com/security/2012/06/flame-crypto-breakthrough/)) and [analysis from Marc Stevens](http://www.cwi.nl/news/2012/cwi-cryptanalist-discovers-new-cryptographic-attack-variant-in-flame-spy-malware).

Comment: I would argue the Terminal Services exploit wasn't that big of a deal.  If the MD5 Collision exploit didn't exist the only operating system that could have been exploited was Windows XP.  People often wonder the reason I dislike Windows XP, the reason should be obvious, it was released in a time before you could be hit by drive by downloads on any compromised website.

Answer (score 25):

> **Update:** [Microsoft published a report](http://blogs.technet.com/b/srd/archive/2012/06/06/more-information-about-the-digital-certificates-used-to-sign-the-flame-malware.aspx) which confirms the guesses in this posting and gives a great level of details.

### Certificate Purpose

There are multiple purposes a certificate may be used for. For example it may be used as a proof of identity of a person or webserver. It may be used for code sining or to sign other certificates.

In this case a certificate that was intended to sign license information was able to sign code.

It might be as simple as Microsoft not checking the purpose-flag of customer certificates they signed:

> Specifically, when an enterprise customer requests a Terminal Services activation license, the certificate issued by Microsoft in response to the request allows code signing.

### MD5 collision attack

The reference to an old algorithm might indicate a collision attack on the signing process: There was a talk at CCC 2008 called **MD5 considered harmful today - Creating a rogue CA Certificate**

- [Website](http://www.win.tue.nl/hashclash/rogue-ca/)
- [Slides](http://events.ccc.de/congress/2008/Fahrplan/attachments/1251_md5-collisions-1.0.pdf)
- [Video](http://media.ccc.de/browse/congress/2008/25c3-3023-en-making_the_theoretical_possible.html)

In that talk the researches explained how to generate two certificates with the same hash.

The generated a harmless looking certification request and submitted it to a CA. The CA signed it and generated the valid certificate for https-servers.

But this certificate had the same hash as another generated certificate which had the purpose CA-certificate. So the CA signature of the harmless certificate was valid for the dangerous one as well.

The researches exploited a weakness in MD5 to generate collisions. In order for the attack to work, they had to predict the information the CA would write into the certificate.

### Lessons learned?

- Microsoft already checks that the root of code signing certificates for Windows Update is a Microsoft CA. So certificates signed by other rouge CAs cannot be used.
- Don't forget legacy code and services
- If there is enough motivation even impractical theoretical weaknesses, will be exploited. (The original title of the talk was "Doing the theoretical possible").

### Update

[Microsoft has confirmed](http://blogs.technet.com/b/msrc/archive/2012/06/04/security-advisory-2718704-update-to-phased-mitigation-strategy.aspx?Redirected=true#fragment-5678) both issues (one issue alone is sufficient for an exploit):

> The Flame malware used a cryptographic collision attack in combination with the terminal server licensing service certificates to sign code as if it came from Microsoft. However, code-signing without performing a collision is also possible.

### Update 2

[Microsoft published the details](http://blogs.technet.com/b/srd/archive/2012/06/06/more-information-about-the-digital-certificates-used-to-sign-the-flame-malware.aspx):

- The vulnerability of not checking the certificate purpose properly only effects old versions of Windows.
- The collision attack was used manipulate the certificate extensions, so that current versions of Windows are fooled as well.

### Update 3

The researchers of the original md5 collision attack published that [the attackers used a new variant of the known md5 chosen prefix attack](http://www.cwi.nl/news/2012/cwi-cryptanalist-discovers-new-cryptographic-attack-variant-in-flame-spy-malware), which implies that they have very deep knowledge about cryptography.

Comment: What surprises me is that md5 certificates are still considered valid. I would have expected that all md5 based certs are considered invalid.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, at the time the vulnerability was published, certificates with MD5 based signature were too wide spread. That the same reason, Verisign was never removed from the list of trusted CAs, although Verisign issued bogus code signing certificates. The attack requires that the information the CA will write into the certificate is predictable at the time the certification request was created. A mitigation is therefore to use random "sequence" numbers.

Comment: Great answer. The reason why D.W. chose to create his own answer (and accept it) is beyond me...

Comment: It's significant to note that Flame used a previously unknown collision attack method.

Comment: @YoavAner, this is indeed a very helpful answer, but I wrote a separate answer because this answer only has half of the story (half of the vulnerability).  My answer also mentions the other half of the story: that Microsoft was giving out a cert that could be used for code signing to everyone, and that this could be exploited independent of the MD5 problem (it could be exploited without using a MD5 collision attack).  Also, at the time I wrote my answer, this answer was speculation, whereas I was able to find and link to more definitive information about what happened.

Answer (score 12):

Nice question :) Not sure if there's an obvious answer.

I didn't think that it was an alogorithm that was broken as such but a stolen cert.

I guess one lesson is that the CA model is broken but then you probably knew that before. So it looks like a real "Microsoft" certificate was used to sign Flame. SANS have posted the following - https://isc.sans.edu/diary.html?storyid=13366. No one currently appears to know how it was stolen etc or who did it yet but would the US govt (who many originally suspected) really steal a Microsoft cert, who knows???

I love the bit in the link you provided where Microsoft say -

"Additionally, most antivirus products will detect and remove this malware."

I think the Flame incident is further evidence that the AV industry is completely reactionary, very much marketing driven and no longer effective (even Mikko Hyponnen said it was a failure in Wired over the weekend - http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2012/06/internet-security-fail/ ).

Hyponnen posted a picture of what the stolen certs used in Flame would look like in Windows 7 prior to revoking them - http://t.co/M7phmvAu.

Someone who knows a lot more than me about certs etc (Moxie Marlinspike) did a great post on that topic last year - http://blog.thoughtcrime.org/ssl-and-the-future-of-authenticity. I've been playing a little with Convergence (http://convergence.io) and I'll probably look into it more, though it's essentially for browsing and won't help here unfortunately. The vast majority of users don't know how to check for certs in their browser or understand how it works, let alone looking at driver certs. I guess it's another example in the importance of truly understanding what you (or your users) are running, doing and what is normal traffic. Building a policy allowing known, good traffic and denying anything not explicitly allowed (to the Internet)  helps reduce the attack surface and capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

> This advice is for those who require the highest security, and not for the casual web user

A lesson we can learn is to reduce the surface area of [public trust](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc751157.aspx).  I don't know what specific root hierarchy was compromised, but in general the out-of-the-box public PKI trust is too broad in my opinion.

I would suggest removing all non-essential root certificates from your hosts [except for those listed here](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=293781):

```
Issued to                              Issued by                            Serial number                   Expiration date Intended purposes   Friendly name                        Status
Microsoft Root Authority               Microsoft Root Authority         00c1008b3c3c8811d13ef663ecdf40  12/31/2020  All                     Microsoft Root Authority                R
Thawte Timestamping CA                 Thawte Timestamping CA           00                              12/31/2020  Time Stamping           Thawte Timestamping CA                  R
Microsoft Root Certificate Authority   Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 79ad16a14aa0a5ad4c7358f407132e65 5/9/2021   All                     Microsoft Root Certificate Authority    R
```

Then petition Microsoft to constrain those trusted roots to the minimum EKU's necessary such as code signing, etc.  Even the constrained list of 3 certificates have too much permission.

Casual users who insist on removing root certificates [should look through this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/15571/396) regarding why the CAs were placed there, the methodology, and the security requirements of each root ca.

Comment: Microsoft Update only trusts the Microsoft CA. Unlike browsers, it ignores all other CAs. That's the reason why Flame had to be signed by a certificate which chains up to the Microsoft CA instead of one of the CAs that cooperate with official organizations.

Comment: One Microsoft certificate that can be removed is the `Microsoft Authenticode(tm) Root Authority`.  That does code signing too.  Regardless if that was the one that was compromised with Flame, I still think the other CAs shouldn't have all purposes enabled.