# Is pinning global root CA almost same as not having any certificate pinning at all?

Tags: certificates, mobile, certificate-pinning

I have seen multiple mobile applications that are pinning Global Root CA's instead of intermediate/leaf certificates. Doesn't this expose to the same risk as not having certificate pinning at all?

Considering the classic coffee shop attack scenario where the owner of the network has a certificate issued for his domain (`*.evilcoffee.com` signed by DigiCert)

Now if the mobile application is trusting any certificate issued by Digicert then you can effectively MiTM?
Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you saying that the application makes a server request, downloads the certificate, then inspects the chain, and then inspects the chain for a matching hash? What library is doing the validation, or is it manual?

Comment: On iOS its using AFNetworking and Android its okHTTP3.
@goodguys_activate Here is some relevant research I have done on this topic: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2744
The application makes a connection to the domain `api.<companyname>.com` The certificate on that domain has the Global Root CA > Intermediate CA > Leaf (which has *.companyname.com as its SAN) 

Instead of pinning the leaf/intermediate they are pinning global root CA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now if the mobile application is trusting any certificate issued by Digicert then you can effectively MiTM? Am I missing something?

Pinning against a CA does not mean that every certificate from this CA will be trusted for a site but that **only** certificates issued by this CA will be **considered to be trustable** in the first place.

CA pinning does not disable any other checks usually done, i.e. checking for the subject (CN/SAN) matching the hostname, certificate not being expired, purpose ... . Thus CA pinning does not allow any certificates which were not allowed without CA pinning. It prevents though trusting other CA to be trusted to issue a certificate for the specific domain.

Pinning against a specific root CA for a domain is like removing any other root CA from the trust store when validating a certificate for this domain.

Answer (score 1):

Pinning a Root CA can prevent risks posed by other trusted Root CAs in the default certificate store. As mentioned in [the link you shared](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2744) (thank you), it's a deployment decision as to how high (or low) in the chain you would pin the certificate.

Check out [this Security.SE post](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/2268/396) for more information for the underlying threat and some mitigations.