# Cookie stealing, what prevents a rogue wireless AP from stealing website cookies?

Tags: cookies, wireless

If you set up a rogue AP with the same SSID as a commonly-known wireless access point, what prevents you from forging DNS queries answering with your own web server and stealing people's login credential cookies?

Comment: I wrote a blog detailing just how simple it can be to access the cookie data and hijack session with it: http://scotthel.me/advsesshijack

Answer (score 2):

"Rouge" is a kind of lipstick. You mean a **rogue** access point.

There is nothing which prevents an evildoer from setting up an access point which mimics, from a outside, an access point that you would like to use. At least for any "open" access point. An attacker could find it somewhat more difficult to mimic an AP that requires authentication and does it properly (WPA2), such that your own computer is aware that authentication is expected and would complain loudly if it is not required by the AP. This also depends a lot on the exact kind of authentication. It is best to assume that rogue access points are always a possibility, and, indeed, ready-to-use hardware for that [is available](http://hakshop.myshopify.com/products/wifi-pineapple).

In reality, this is not different, **qualitatively**, from the Internet "in general". It should always be assumed that anything which goes over the Internet can be eavesdropped on and altered and rerouted; the WiFi part is just the first step in the journey over the wild Internet, and it is no more protected than all the others, despite tenacious beliefs to the contrary. (I think it comes from the authentication with a password; people think that "if there is a password then it is *secure*", without realizing that the password is not for *their* protection, but to limit access to the Internet access which is *beyond* the access point.)

The comprehensive solution against cookie stealing is [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) (aka "HTTP-within-SSL"). Even attackers who can redirect your requests to their own server cannot impersonate an `https://` powered Web site (and steal the corresponding cookies), at least as long as:

- the site does things properly (i.e., mostly, site-wide HTTPS, with no HTTP-only part, and cookies flagged as [Secure and HttpOnly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_and_HttpOnly));
- *you* take care to use HTTPS and not be directed to an HTTP-only clone of the site, in particular if the site requests a password entry;
- you do not "click through" any warning about a bad certificate (and that's crucial for the whole thing).

Comment: "rouge" is applied to cheeks, not lips, here in North America.

Answer (score -2):

In short, nothing. The only way to be totally safe would be to use a VPN through the untrusted network.

Once they have access to your traffic they could just use an SSL (TLS) interception proxy and MITM even HTTPS connections.

Comment: HTTPS prevents MITM.

Comment: No it doesn't: http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS

Comment: The user is most likely to either not see or ignore any warnings and simply bypass them to continue using the website. It's also covered here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8145/does-https-prevent-man-in-the-middle-attacks-by-proxy-server If the user clicks through, the proxy can access traffic.