# Security during data transfer

Tags: wifi

I am downloading a file from a http site on an wifi network. Is it possible(even theoretically) to change the contents of the file(or replace it with a malicious variant) during the download process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, an attacker can perform a man-in-the-middle attack against your requests over the network and replace  the file your requested with his -malicious- own.

Comment: That means that the attack will also be possible on a MITM'd https connection?

Comment: @MayankSingh **no**, and that is one of the advantages of HTTPS

Comment: This is not a 100% correct. There are possible weaknesses in SSL that allow for attacks. E.g. i remember signed certificates being compromised some years ago.

Or remember the [Goto-Fail] (https://gotofail.com/) from MacOS? That one rendered SSL completely useless. 

If you want to have a better insight, this stackoverflow question should do it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907581/ssl-and-man-in-the-middle-misunderstanding

Comment: @Gewure Yes, nothing is 100%, you can always allure a malinformed user visiting an HTTPS url to an HTTP one, but you can not perform MITM on HTTPS protocol. Maybe you can read the answer to this:

Comment: @Gewure http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8145/does-https-prevent-man-in-the-middle-attacks-by-proxy-server