# Invisible SSL sniffing

Tags: tls, certificate-authority, sniffing

My question is pretty brief: may I accomplish invisible sniffing of secure traffic with(HTTPS)  via sniffer, using my own certificate but signed by some commonly known CA(like verisign or smth like this) ?

The aim of this operation is pretty obvious - be invisible for user whose traffic will be sniffed. Because without root CA's signature, when certificates chain will be interrupted, user will be shown an alert about my custom certificate.

So, having my custom certificate signed by CA, there will no any alerts?

Comment: [Does https prevent man in the middle attacks by proxy server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8145/) describes how such man in the middle attacks work. For more details see also [How does SSL/TLS work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work). Once you've understood this you should be able to answer your question. If not please add enough detail on exactly what kind of certificate you want to use in your attack and how you want to get it, because it would need at least to be issued by a trusted CA **and match the URL**.

Comment: "match the URL" - I missed that, thanks P.S this question is not duplicate - it is question, appeared after reading those article