# MTproto Proxy Security in Telegram App

Tags: encryption, cryptography, proxy, smartphone, telegram

In `Telegram` messenger, latest update, there is an option to set connection type to MTProto Proxy.

Note: There is a detailed description by Telegram team on [MTProto](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto).

Now telegram officially announced that the Data encrypted in MTProto Proxy can not be deciphered by any third party due to the usage of end-to-end encryption.

[image]

Logically, Is it possible to implement a method that proxy server is not able to interpret passing data to Telegram Server at all?

Answer (score 1):

> Logically, Is it possible to implement a method that proxy server is not able to interpret passing data to Telegram Server at all?

That's not specific to Telegram. If you are using a HTTP or SOCKS proxy to visit site with HTTPS you still have end-to-end encryption, i.e. the proxy sees only encrypted traffic. It is different when having a SSL intercepting proxy which one usually finds in companies but also as local proxy in antivirus products. In this case the proxy will decrypt end re-encrypt the traffic in order to analyze it. But this would also mean that your client is explicitly trusting the proxy to do this, see [Does https prevent man in the middle attacks by proxy server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8145/does-https-prevent-man-in-the-middle-attacks-by-proxy-server)
 for more details about SSL interception.

But even if an SSL intercepting proxy is used it would still be possible to add yet another level of end-to-end encryption on top of it with fixed information of what kind of end-system is expected, i.e. similar to [certificate pinning](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29988/what-is-certificate-pinning). Even an SSL intercepting proxy will only see the encrypted traffic and might decide to pass it or block it but will not be able to look further into it.