# SSL/TLS Protocol Description

Tags: tls

It may seem crazy to you, but I wasn't able to find any detailed description of these security protocols on the web (except [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)).

Can you point me out some documentation of the protocols implementations?

Comment: Is there anything more specific that you want to know about?

Comment: @Bruno i would like to know about the handshake protocol

Comment: There is now a [dedicated question on security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-work) on that subject, with detailed answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add to Gurzo's list, here are a few other links with diagrams:

- [Microsoft Technet: SSL/TLS in details](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785811%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
- [Microsoft Technet: How TLS/SSL Works](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783349%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
- [Oracle JSSE Reference Guide: SSL Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SSLOverview)

For the actual references:

- [SSL 3.0](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/ssl/draft302.txt)
- [TLS 1.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246)
- [TLS 1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346)
- [TLS 1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246)

Proper usage of SSL/TLS also depends on other factors. In general, X.509 certificates will also be used and verified using the [PKIX specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) (not an easy read if you're new to the field). (Other types of certificates/authentication methods can be used in some cases.)
You may also want to tie this up with the certificate host name verification: [RFC 2818 (section 3.1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1) (HTTPS) and [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125) (more general). These are not part of SSL/TLS as such, but are part of the overall picture to establish a secure connection.

(If you're also after the difference between SSL, TLS and their usage modes such as STARTTLS, you may also want to have a look at this [rather detailed answer on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/368574/47187) I wrote a few weeks ago.)

Comment: Perhaps you might also be interested in this question: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/10022/2435

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, was it me blind, or you who knew were to look? ;D

Answer (score 4):

A quick Google search returned:

- [Links to Related RFCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Standards)
- [SSL/TLS Strong Encryption: An Introduction](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_intro.html)
- [Introduction to SSL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_SSL)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, was it me blind, or you who knew were to look? ;D

Comment: TBH, I just googled it and checked for reliable domains ;)