# Why middleman cannot capture the encryption key of https/tor traffic?

Tags: encryption, tls, tor

When we use Tor or https traffic , the encryption- decryption key has to be exchanged between the browser and the website server. Why somebody who can capture entire traffic , say ISP or somebody who controls the wifi router, cannot capture the key and hence read the actual content of the encrypted traffic ?

Comment: this link answers it in best possible manner
http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6290/how-is-it-possible-that-people-observing-an-https-connection-being-established-w

Answer (score 0):

This is the basics of [Asymmetric Key Encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) (or public key encryption).  Each party has a key pair, a public key and private key.

You can encrypt data with the public key, but it can only be decrypted with the private key.  Now, there is a performance hit when using public keys, so usually a symmetric key is set up.  The problem is that we need to have a secure way to distribute our key.    Public key cryptography is used to securely exchange that key.

In it's most simplified form, a client creates a secret key K, and encrypt this using the server's public key. Now, only the server can decrypt this, and K is used to encrypt all further traffic.

K is never transferred in clear text, so even though an ISP collects all traffic between client and server, they'll never know what K is.  (That is, unless there are vulnerabilities).

As said, there's a lot more to see (SSL negotiation, etc...) when setting up an SSL tunnel, but that's the general idea.