# Why is it not a good idea to simply encrypt the plaintext with the receiver’s public key?

Tags: encryption, aes, rsa, public-key, cbc

**What are some of the risks when encrypting "plaintext" with a receiver's public key?**

I have been Googling for hours, and been reading in the `Computer Security Principles and Practice 3rd edition`.

It's NOT similar:
[In PGP, why not just encrypt message with recipient's public key? Why the meta-encryption?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20134/in-pgp-why-not-just-encrypt-message-with-recipients-public-key-why-the-meta-e)

Comment: Can you explain how it is not similar? The original version of your question appears to be exactly the same.

Comment: If you follow the answers in the duplicate, there are no risks except the operational ones. Why are you hunting for risks when you can find no basis for a threat? Or, perhaps, who told you that there were risks?

Comment: What does this question really mean: "Why is it not a good idea to simply encrypt the plaintext with the receiver’s public key?" then? I am confused.

Comment: What does it *really* mean? I don't know. It is your question. But reading this question and the other and its answers, it appears to answer what you asked. If it does not, then can you explain why it is not satisfactory for your needs?